# C++ was designed to operate within a single address space

Tags: c++, operating-system

I had just started learning C++. I am using Stroustrup as my reference book. While going through its introductory chapter, i came across this line which I was unable to understand.

"C++ was designed to operate within a single address space"

Can anybody please explain what does it mean?

Comment: use google http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_address_space_operating_system

Comment: It means that you can have problems. For example, Visual Studio may link the runtime (the core of C++) statically into your binary code (it is copied together your executable). Each runtime will use its own address space. If you use two binaries (an executable and a shared library) with their own runtimes, and you allocate memory in one of them and try to release it in the other, you'll have a crash: the second runtime is trying to release a region of memory in its own address space, while it actually belongs to other one.

Comment: I completely disagree with @kylecorver here. SASOP are completely different things. They put *all processes* in the same operating system, while most OS put each process in their own address space. The page you want to read is more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space

Answer (score -1):

It's actually untrue today. C++ is in fact designed to operate with one or two address spaces. If code and data are separate, you have two address spaces.

An address space is the range of possible pointer values. Since a `void*` can point to **any** object, this means that all objects are in the address range of `void*`. However, it's unspecified whether a `void*` can point to a function. Hence, the address space of functions may be distinct from the address space of objects.

However, originally C++ was designed on machines which did in fact have a unified address space, where objects and functions could be mixed. POSIX and Windows actually require this, because `dlsym`/`GetProcAddress` support both functions and object lookup.

Comment: Code and data at still part of the same address space. In a modern system they various types of pages may congregate together in program sections but they remain in the same address space. Even with the dying concept of segments, they are still in the address space, counting the segment selector.

Comment: @user3344003: There are embedded systems where the code is in ROM, and isn't even organized in bytes (!) Now these systems today are too small for C++, but they definitely support C. And C has pretty much the same rules for pointers (data and functions are logically separate even if physically identical)

Comment: This answer seem to intermix between "address space" and "memory segment". Moreover, data and code can be located into the same memory segment...

Comment: @MartinQuinson: Of course data and code can be mixed on hardware that allows it. As for "intermixing" address space and "memory segment", there are no hard and formal distinctions between the two terms. There's an infinite number of reasonable hardware architectures, with varying degrees of separation between code and data.